# resize a picture after upload in php

Tags: php, image, resize

I'm trying to resize a picture after upload so I did a code like that :

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' AND isset($_FILES['images'])) {
    $target_folder = 'upload/';
    $nom_image = $_FILES['images']['name'];
    $tmp_image = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $upload_image = $target_folder . basename($nom_image);
    //JE RECUPERE L'IMAGE EN JPG :
    $ImageChoisie = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_image);
    //JE VERIFIE SA TAILLE :
    $TailleImageChoisie = getimagesize($tmp_image);
    //JE DEFINIS LA NOUVELLE TAILLE DE L'IMAGE QUI SERA INSEREE :
    $NouvelleTailleImage = 200;
    //JE CALCULE LE POURCENTAGE DE REDUCTION :
    $Reduction = ( ($NouvelleTailleImage * 100) / $TailleImageChoisie[0] );
    //JE DEFINIS LA NOUVELLE LARGEUR DE L'IMAGE :
    $NouvelleLargeurImage = ( ($TailleImageChoisie[0] * $Reduction) / 100);
    //ON CREE DONC UN DOUBLE DE L'IMAGE QUI SERA CELLE AFFICHEE :
    $ImageChoisie = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_image);
    $NouvelleImage = imagecreatetruecolor($NouvelleTailleImage, $NouvelleLargeurImage) or die("Erreur");
    //PUIS JE COPIE ET JE REECHANTILLONNE L'IMAGE DE DEPART :
    imagecopyresampled($NouvelleImage, $ImageChoisie, 0, 0, 0, 0, $NouvelleLargeurImage, $NouvelleLargeurImage, $TailleImageChoisie[0], $TailleImageChoisie[1]);
    //JE N'AI PLUS QU'A DETRUIRE L'IMAGE CHOISIE AU DEPART QUI NE SERT PLUS A RIEN :
    imagedestroy($ImageChoisie);
    // JE NE GARDE QUE LE NOM DE L'IMAGE SANS SON EXTENSION :
    $NomImageChoisie = explode('.', $nom_image);
    //JE L'APPELLE $NomImageExploitable :
    $NomImageExploitable = '';
    // JE NOMME LE PREMIER TERME DE L'EXPLODE : i
    $i = 0;
    //JE DECOUPE LE TERME NomImage EN AUTANT DE CHAÎNE QU'il Y EN A GRACE A -1, ET LE PREMIER TERME JE L'APPELLE $NomImage[0]
    while ($i < (count($NomImageChoisie) - 1)) {
        $NomImageExploitable = $NomImageChoisie[0];
        $i++;
    }
    //LA PREMIERE CHAINE EST NomImageExploitable, JE LA PASSE EN IMAGEJPEG POUR EN CREER UN FICHIER JPEG AVEC UNE QUALITE DE  100 :
    imagejpeg($NouvelleImage, 'uploads/' . $NomImageExploitable . '.jpg', 100);
    //LE LIEN VERS L'IMAGE EST DONC :
    $Lienimages = 'uploads/' . $NomImageExploitable . '.jpg';

//    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $upload_image)) {
//        exec('convert ' . $upload_image . ' -resize ' . $newwidth . 'x' . $newheight . '^ ' . $thumbnail);
//        rename($upload_image, $actual);
//    }
}
```

I use the variable SuperGlobal $_FILES but in some lines it returns to me errors.

```
warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\cyb2.fr\private_area\plugin-upload\upload.php on line 19
```

the same here :

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\cyb2.fr\private_area\plugin-upload\upload.php on line 21
```

anykind of help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_FILES['images']['name'] is an array, you have to use $_FILES['images']['name'][$i] in a loop, with $i = 0 to $i = count($_FILES['images']['name']) - 1

Comment: salut Pierre Emmanuel, j'ai déjà essayé cette solution mais ça me renvoit les même messages d'erreur.

Comment: fais un "var_dump($_FILES['images']['name']); exit;" avant le "$target_folder = 'upload/';", et fais un upload. Ca t'affichera le contenu de $_FILES['images']['name']. Procède ainsi au fur et à mesure pour débugger le code (avec d'autres var_dump des variables)

Comment: merci pour ton aide :)